# Find missing values, constrained by another value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables. Table1 contains unique account numbers, and unique account names.  Table2 contains related account numbers to Table1's account numbers, but also another "parent" account number.

I am trying to find all the account numbers that exist in Table1, but do not exist in Table2.  Furthermore, I would like to each missing account number that is missing per the "parent" account number in Table2.

Ex.

Table1

```
AccountNum  AccountName
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
```

Table2

```
ParentAccount  AccountNum  AccountName
100            1           a
100            2           b
200            1           a
200            2           b
200            4           d
```

I would like my result to return:

```
100            3           c
100            4           d
200            3           c
```

So far I can only figure out how to return values that don't exist in Table 2 at all, but not restricted by parent account.  I would separate out the tables, but I have hundreds of parent accounts.

```
SELECT Table1.AccountNum, Table1.AccountName
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.[AccountNum] = Table2.[AccountNum]
WHERE (((Table2.AccountNum) Is Null));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been stuck on this for quite some time now and am working in Access 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by creating a saved query named [AccountCombinations] that gives us all combinations of ParentAccount and AccountNum:

```
SELECT t2.ParentAccount, t1.AccountNum, t1.AccountName
FROM 
Table1 t1,
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ParentAccount FROM Table2
) t2
```

That query returns

```
ParentAccount  AccountNum  AccountName
-------------  ----------  -----------
          100           1  a          
          200           1  a          
          100           2  b          
          200           2  b          
          100           3  c          
          200           3  c          
          100           4  d          
          200           4  d
```

Now we can just extract the ones that don't exist in Table2

```
SELECT * 
FROM AccountCombinations
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table2
    WHERE AccountCombinations.ParentAccount=Table2.ParentAccount
        AND AccountCombinations.AccountNum=Table2.AccountNum
)
ORDER BY ParentAccount, AccountNum
```

...returning...

```
ParentAccount  AccountNum  AccountName
-------------  ----------  -----------
          100           3  c          
          100           4  d          
          200           3  c
```